# Constructive proof that tensor product distributes over direct sum?

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, tensor-products

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with 1, and $M$, $N_i$ be $R$-modules. For a given index set $I$, every proof I've seen that $M\otimes(\oplus_{i\in I} N_i) \cong \oplus_{i\in I}(M\otimes N_i)$ proceed via using the universal property of the tensor product. Is there a way to do this constructively?

What I've tried is the following. We know that we create a free module $F$ by assigning each $(m,(n_i)_{i\in I})$ a free generator $\delta(m,(n_i)_{i\in I})$. Similarly, we could consider the direct sum of the free modules $F_i$ given in the construction of $M\otimes N_i$, namely by assigning each element $(m,n_i)$ a free generator $\delta_i(m,n_i)$. Then, elements of $\oplus_{i\in I} F_i$ should look like finite sums of these $\delta_i(m,n_i)$.

Using the above, the natural injection (in a formal sense) $F\to \oplus F_i$ would be to map $\delta(m,(n_i)_{i\in I})\mapsto \sum_{i\in I} \delta_i(m,n_i)$. Unfortunately, unless $I$ is finite, there is no reason to think that the sum on the right-hand side would be finite. Moreover, I don't see any way this map could ever be surjective.

Does anyone have any thoughts on how to reconcile this? I know the universal property is the 'correct' way to approach things with the tensor product, but I'd also like to know exactly where this line of thinking fails.

Comment: What definition of the tensor product are you using? I am most used to a definition involving the universal property.

Comment: The one given in Atiyah-Macdonald.

Comment: They give a definition in terms of universal property (on page 24). Only when proving existence do they use something different

Comment: By definition of the direct sum, in your $(m,(n_i)_{i\in I})$ only a finite set of $n_i$'s are non-zero. Same in your $\sum_{i\in I} \delta_i(m,n_i).$